# Hide the CONTENT of a Pidgin Notification Only

Tags: skype, pidgin

I'm looking for a way to hide only the content of a Pidgin notification, e.g. the message body for a Skype message. I'd like the notification to still pop up, but it should be more discreet in the event that someone else is nearby when a message arrives. Is there a way to do this natively or with a 3rd-party plugin/mod?

Comment: What's the current desktop you are using?

Comment: @xangua I'm running 16.04 with Unity.